# How can a video File (.MOV) play perfectly in VLC and other players but not open in Premiere Pro?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, quicktime, adobe-premiere

A four Gig Quicktime (.MOV) video file (a video taken on an iPhone) plays perfectly on VLC, Windows Media Player and PotPlayer but when imported into Adobe Premiere Pro 5.5 the following error message appears :

"The file has no audio or video streams".

All other videos from the same day open perfectly in Adobe Premiere Pro.

I've tried four different video file converter / repair tools (including Remo, Stellar Phoenix and StreamClip). Three of the tools actually worsened the problem instead of fixing it. They made the file unplayable (as well as not editable). As a precaution, I only tried the repair tools on a backup of the file so as not to ruin the original.

I've searched but cannot find an example of a video file that plays back perfectly but cannot be imported into Premiere.

Can anyone suggest a way of extracting the (clearly) uncorrupted video from this .MOV file?

Comment: As Premier Pro CS5.5 was [released in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Premiere_Pro#Release_history) it might be that they never expected to have a >4GB video file and it is simply unsupported. Try a newer version?

Comment: I tried to find out if there is a limit but the answer was not clear. Some folks reported to have found some kind of limit at 4Gigs but others refuted that. Apparently "4gb is nothing in the video editing world".

Comment: I suspect the limit is format dependant, I know mp4 files encoded by Handbrake can have a "large format" option which apparently uses a [64-bit format instead of 32-bit](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/letsplay/comments/30myg1/any_help_with_handbrake_no_large_file_size_check/) for data chunk mapping and it is possible that it is this that imposes a 4GB limit if CS5.5 does not support it. (Not an answer because this is only a guess)